# What did the ancient rabbis teach about the "new minchah" (Leviticus 23:16 and Numbers 28:26)?

Tags: halacha, mincha-afternoon-prayer, shavuos, bamidbar-numbers-book-of, mincha-meal-offering

What did the ancient rabbis teach about the "new minchah" (Leviticus 23:16 and Numbers 28:26)?

In shul, the discussion was about counting the omer. And then a mention of the "new minchah", with various esoteric applications.

I was not able to follow the teaching, and the sing-song way that the rabbi was doing did not help. Hence my question.

I am interested in what the ancient rabbis from the Talmud or Midrash or Kabbalah, etc., said about the New Minchah.

Comment: What shul and what Rabbi? Knowing that might help in understanding what he/they were discussing.

Comment: I am in Europe. It was a visiting chabad speaker.